# Why do DVDs work even when they vibrate?

Tags: dvd

This is a hardware question: DVD writers and players all vibrate a little, presumably because the media is not perfectly balanced. All I know is that the raw information on the drive is coded in such a way that errors are well tolerated. Without getting too much into the details, I'm just curious how they work around this vibration considering how dense the data is. Maybe I can just ask this as multiple choice, I have several hypotheses:

a - The media and mechanical parts of the drive all are bonded together so the head moves in sync with the vibrations

b - There is some clever feedback mechanism that keeps the head in line with the track while it vibrates

c - There is something about the way the optics work that makes the mechanism insensitive to vibrations (including the way the data is coded on the disc.)

d - The amplitude of the vibration is less than the tolerance of the track width so it's nothing to worry about

e - All of the above

Comment: A, the read head is part of the drive spindle assembly, they both move to the same inbalance, then error correction takes care of the rest. its not some "feedback" mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b - There is some clever feedback mechanism that keeps the head in line with the track while it vibrates.

More information from [Phil Frost's post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/74776/36731): "The lens is moved by what is essentially a [voice coil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_coil). There will be several, oriented perpendicularly, in order to orient the lens in multiple dimensions."

Answer (score 0):

I took one apart to show you that the laser and the spindle are mounted to the same steel sub chassis inside this cd rom drive, so most of the vibration due to disc imbalance is transmitted to the outer chassis via the four rubber mount points and not the laser/lense. One could assume after a little wear and tear on the spindle bearings the imbalance could cause read issues by allowing the disc to move around on its axis. So A is my answer.

[image]